# $XP_{\text{uniform}}=FPT$ and update to $EPTAS$ section in complexity zoo?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, approximation-algorithms, parameterized-complexity

Complexity zoo in https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#eptas has the following:

$FPT = XPuniform\implies EPTAS = PTAS$.

[Fundamentals of Parametrized complexity](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.2729&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on page $534$ has

[image]

which from "we will only look at XP and
remark that all the results hold with no change for uniform XP as well. By
standard diagonalization, we have the following basic result:

Proposition $27.3.1$. FPT is a proper subset of XP."

means $FPT$ is a proper subset of $XP_{uniform}$ as well.

1. Is this correct information? If so this result has been known for a long time. So is there any updates that need to be made to complexity zoo section https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#eptas and is there any consequences to approximation algorithms because of this?
2. Does $FPT=W[P]$ have any consequences to approximation algorithms? I see only reverse consequences in complexity zoo:

[image]

Comment: We should have $FPT \neq XP_{uniform}$.  Suppose for sake of contradiction that they were equal.  Then, it would follow that there exists $c$ such that $PTIME = DTIME(n^c)$.  This cannot be true by the time hierarchy theorem so we get a contradiction.

Comment: I believe that if $FPT = W[P]$, then we would get faster algorithms for circuit SAT.  This is mentioned on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity .  If $FPT = W[P]$ were true, then we might also obtain new circuit lower bounds.

Comment: @MichaelWehar Yes $FPT=W[P]$ is stronger than non-$ETH$.